# Как отсортировать массив по количеству элементов в его подмассивах?

Tags: php

Есть многомерный массив с одним уровнем вложенности

```
$arr = [
    [1,2,], //2 элемента
    [1,4,5], //3
    [1,], //1
    [1,4,6,9], //4
];
```

Как можно отсортировать в обратном порядке массивы первого уровня по количеству элементов в этих массивах. В итоге должно получиться вот так. Индексы не важны.

```
$arr = [
    [1,4,6,9], //4
    [1,4,5], //3
    [1,2,], //2
    [1,], //1
];
```

Как это можно сделать?

Пробовал вот так, но это не то, что нужно.

```
usort($arr, function($key, $value) {
    return count($value);
});

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Пробовали что-то уже? `usort` например.

Comment: @u_mulder да, дополнил вопрос. Возможно, я не так использую функцию

Comment: `usort($arr, fn($a, $b) => count($b) <=> count($a));`

Answer (score 2):

`usort` вторым аргументом принимает `callback` функцию, которая должна возвращать целое, которое меньше, равно или больше нуля, если первый аргумент является соответственно меньшим, равным или большим, чем второй. `$a` и `$b` - это по порядку сравниваемые элементы массива, а не key и value как в вашем примере.

```php
$arr = [
    [1,2,], //2 элемента
    [1,4,5], //3
    [1,], //1
    [1,4,6,9], //4
];

usort($arr, static function ($a, $b) {
    return count($a) < count($b);
});
```